# Trying to cache with Alamofire with no results

Tags: swift, caching, alamofire

I'm trying to use Alamofire Cache, so my desired behavior would be to load the first time from web and next times if data is present on cache return it without make more requests...after I'll think about expiration...

My code returns always response nil...any suggestions on this? Thanks

```
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    config.URLCache = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache()
    config.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad
    let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: config)
    manager.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .URL, headers: ["Token":LocalStorage.read("token") as! String, "Version":"2"]).responseJSON { (response) in

        if let json = response.result.value
        {
            if response.response?.statusCode == 200
            {
                completionHandler(parser.parseSwifty(JSON(json)), nil)
            }
            else
            {
                completionHandler(nil, serverErrorMessage)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            completionHandler(nil, networkErrorMessage)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So...I resolved this issue:
in my NetworkHelper I added a computed property like so:

```
    static let manager: Manager = {
    let memoryCapacity = 100 * 1024 * 1024; // 100 MB
    let diskCapacity = 100 * 1024 * 1024; // 100 MB
    let cache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: memoryCapacity, diskCapacity: diskCapacity, diskPath: "shared_cache")

    let configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Token":LocalStorage.read("token") as! String, "Version":"2"]
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = .ReturnCacheDataElseLoad // this is the default
    configuration.URLCache = cache

    return Manager(configuration: configuration)
}()
```

and when I have to retrieve some data:

```
        self.manager.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .URL)
        .response { (request, response, data, error) in
            debugPrint(request)
            debugPrint(response)
            debugPrint(error)
    }.responseJSON......
```

I also write a func to preload some data like this:

```
    static func preloadGetRequest(url : String, parameters: Dictionary<String, String>?)
{
    self.manager.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .URL)
        .response { (request, response, data, error) in
            debugPrint(request)
            debugPrint(response)
            debugPrint(error)
    }
}
```

Try and let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the correct way is to create Session Manager early on before calling the request or else the request would always returns nil.

```
var sessionManager: SessionManager!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
    sessionManager = SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
}

//later on
@objc private func refreshWeatherData(_ sender: Any) {
    // Fetch Weather Data
    sessionManager.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .response { (data) in
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        if let data = data.data {
            let json = try? JSON(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

or create a URLRequest with caching policy like so

```
@objc private func refreshWeatherData(_ sender: Any) {
    // Fetch Weather Data
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!, cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 100)        
    Alamofire.request(request)
    .response { (data) in
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        if let data = data.data {
            let json = try? JSON(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```